# Xamarin MainPage DatePicker Reference in View

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

very simple, I have a Datepicker in my MainPage with the x:Name of 'TheDate' how do I get it referenced in my ViewPage.xaml.cs.

MainPage.Xaml Code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="10" Margin="0, 20, 0, 20">
     <Label Text="Date" WidthRequest="384" FontSize="24"/>
     <DatePicker x:Name="TheDate" WidthRequest="384" FontSize="24" Margin="0, -10, 0, 0" />
</StackLayout>
```

AccordionView.Xaml.cs Code:

```
 public async void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { //WANT TO ADD THE THEDATE HERE }
```

Comment: Please improve your question by adding some relevant code and more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL/DR:** You can't.

**Long version:** You should not, but there is another way: You have a view (`AccordionView`) that lives within the scope of your `MainPage`. While it might be technically possible to add a reference to `TheDate` to the `AccordionView`, I'd argue not to do this. This would make `AccordionView` depend on implementation details of its parent, which is most likely a bad idea.

Anyway, what you **can** do - if it makes sense, that your `AccordionView` has a `Date` - is to add a `BindableProperty` with type `DateTime` to your `AccordionView`

```
// Within AccordionView.xaml.cs
public static BindableProperty DateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Date), typeof(DateTime), typeof(AccordionView), default(DateTime));

public DateTime Date
{
    get => (DateTime)GetValue(DateProperty);
    set => SetValue(DateProperty, value);
}
```

Now you'll be able to bind the date from the `DatePicker` from your `MainPage.xaml`

```
<controls:AccordionView Date="{Binding Source={x:Reference TheDate}, Path=Date}" ...>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is what i needed!

Comment: @SodiKZ125 Glad I could help :)

Comment: When changing the datepicker to a entry and changing datetime to string it returns null? how would that work with a entry?

Comment: <Entry x:Name="FormIdMain" IsVisible="True" Text="{Binding FormId}" />

Comment: <local:AccordionView HeaderText="Walsham's Chiller Unit 21" AccordionIDText="WCU21" FormId="{Binding Source={x:Reference FormIdMain}, Path=FormId}"></local:AccordionView>

Comment: `FormIdMain` is an `Entry`, which has no `FormId` property. You'll either have to add `FormId` bindable property to your `MainView` or bind the accordion with `{Binding Source={x:Reference FormIdMain}, Path=Text}` and omit the binding in your entry.

Comment: right that makes sense that the path is looking for the attribute of the entry, i believe it is working correctly.

Comment: Last question its returning null in the constructor on load but on a save button it returns the value

Answer (score 0):

You should just reference the datepicker, and extract the Date (the selected value)

```
 public async void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

     var selectedDate = TheDate.Date;
  }
```

This method must be in the codebehind of the page with the DatePicker in xaml